# sync two local and remote sql server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want sync two server in such way when my local server is connected to internet then both database exchange data.

I have try server database mirroring but my requirement is little different

1) I want both principal and mirror are present at same time

2) when local server is connected to internet then the exchange updates

3) local user connect to local server and web user connect to remote-server
What is the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is using [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx).

This is a series of techniques that allows you to query and modify data in several different instances of SQL Server, and later synchronize them. But it's not magic. It's in fact quite hard to implement because there are a lot of things to take into account:

- generation of unique Ids in several independent servers (so that there are no collissions between them)
- control of what needs to be updated in one server from the other, and viceversa
- resolution of conflicts: for example a row which was updated on two different servers after the last syncronization

SQL Server Replication will help you to manage all these problems, but you still have to do some work so that it works fine. It offers techniques like:

- row versioning (to know what needs to be synchronized from one server on the other)
- reservation of PK ranges for each server (to avoid PK conflictsbetween servers)
- use of GUIS for PKs (solves easyly the previous problem, but overloads the PK indexes)
- use of publisher-suscriptor pattern (so that one server can subscribe to changes from other)